# trying to install Ipython on version 2.7 but it keeps trying to install on version 2.5

Tags: python, installation, ipython

I am trying to install Ipython 0.12 on to python 2.7. Because I'm using a MacBook python 2.5 was already installed as standard on OSX, when i try installing ipython with `python setup.py install` I get a message saying `ERROR: 'IPython requires Python Version 2.6 or above.'` I believe it is trying to install ipython on version 2.5

How can I change that to install on version 2.7 which is the one I use.

Comment: What do you get when you type "which python"?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python

Comment: If you type `python` and hit tab, see if there's a name like `python2.7` that you can run instead.

Comment: Yep, @ThomasK is right.  You can also change the symlinks, but it's easier just to specify the "right" python when using setup.py, pip, and easy_install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

There should be a name like `python2.7`, so running `python2.7 setup.py install` will install it for Python 2.7. This is the same for all packages.

If you want to use a tool like easy_install or pip, they also need to be installed for the relevant version of Python.